# Guardar el texto de radiobutton en variable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, radiobutton

Quisiera guardar el texto de un radio button en una variable, y no tengo idea por donde encararlo. Para el ejemplo, tengo los RB con textos de daños: "chapa", "pintura", "vidrios", "ruedas". Al seleccionar, quiero guardar ese texto en una variable, para luego insertarlo en la DB (esto lo tengo resuelto), pero ... Cómo sería? Gracias

Comment: Puedes ponernos tu codigo de lo que llevas , nos facilitaria ayudarte.Saludos

Comment: Hola, Vizz3rdriX, ¿podrías mostrar el código que estás usando para el ejemplo? Se me ocurre que podrías utilizar la propiedad "text", por ejemplo: `Dim texto as string = miradiob.Text.ToString`, por favor, formula bien tu pregunta mostrando un poco del código.

Comment: El código no lo tengo, porque esta en la pc de un compañero, pero logró solucionarlo, y exactamente con el ejemplo que diste tu. Muchas Gracias!